# How can I justify that the open interval $(0,1)$ is the infinite union of closed intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I have to show that:

$$\bigcup_{i=2}^\infty [\frac{1}{n},\frac{n-1}{n}] = (0,1)$$

The first part:

$$\bigcup_{i=2}^\infty [\frac{1}{n},\frac{n-1}{n}] \subset (0,1)$$

is easy to show, but for the second part:

$$(0,1) \subset \bigcup_{i=2}^\infty [\frac{1}{n},\frac{n-1}{n}]$$

I don't have any idea how to prove it.  I can't use the Principle of Nested Intervals because it's clear that if $I_{k}=[\frac{1}{k},\frac{k-1}{k}]$ where $k$ is a natural number, $I_{k+1} \not\subset I_{k}$ and I have the union.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given $x \in (0,1)$, choose a natural number $n > \text{max}\{2,\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{1-x}\}$; that number exists by the Archmidean principle.

It follows that $x > \frac{1}{n}$ and that $x < \frac{n-1}{n}$ and so $x \in [\frac{1}{n},\frac{n-1}{n}]$.

Comment: the $n$ that you choose is for $n \ge 2$ ? or it follows by  $n>max{ \{\frac{1}{x},\frac{x}{1-x}}\};$ ?

Comment: I threw a $2$ into the formula for $n$, to cover that necessity.

Answer (score 5):

The key things are that

$$\begin{cases}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} &=0\\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n-1}{n} &=1
\end{cases}$$

Therefore any point in $(0,1)$ is included in a closed interval $[1/n, {n-1}/n]$ for $n$ properly chosen.

Comment: (I inadvertently downvoted your post earlier, despite your good answer.  The only way I could undo the downvote was via a minor edit, to restore your upvote count.)

Comment: Ok thanks for that. Normaly if you click  again thé  downvote arrow, it cancels thé downvote.

Comment: Not after a few minutes of the downvote. Try it out somewhere where you may have downvoted (or upvoted) a post, more than a few minutes ago.  Typically, after a short span of time, unless there is an edit, one cannot change the vote.  Anyway, +1 for the trouble I caused you!

Comment: Thanks. No worries anyhow!